# Code::blocks debugging: Do not step into header files

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks for an upcoming college programming course and wanted to find out if there is a way to step through code only in the current project, and not jump into individual header files (iomanip, iostream, stdio, etc.)?

Right now, when I use step into, it steps into each header file for calls like setw or other function calls. Is there anyway to disable this functionality similar to "Step filters" in eclipse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For MSVC there is options known as "Just My Code"

[MSVC - Debug Just My Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You just dont press F11 equivalent (step into) button when you are on library function like `printf(...)`

I agree that is little bit of pain when you have many library function in your function all (single line)

You can check someting similar for code block

Comment: It seems that only works for .net applications under visual studio not native c++.

Comment: I have looked through every option in Code::Blocks and cannot find one.